# How To Import Movielens Data To Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i import UTF-8 data form Movielens to MySql.

I get the data from http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ and for my recommender system Thesis purpose, i just want the 100K and Tag Gnome data only.

I've been searching on google and in this forum and i don't find anything about importing these files to MySQl. Myself, currently using PhpMyAdmin for managing MySQL, so if anybody know how to easily import those files to MySQL.

I'm fine if you guys recommend me to iterate it one by one using php, but please explain to me the code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write some custom code to import all of their data into MySQL.  Dumbest answer on Stack Overflow ever, right?

So they provide a set of flat files, each described in the README.

```
README
allbut.pl
mku.sh
u.data
u.genre
u.info
u.item
u.occupation
u.user
u1.base
u1.test
u2.base
u2.test
u3.base
u3.test
u4.base
u4.test
u5.base
u5.test
ua.base
ua.test
ub.base
ub.test
```

In a nutshell:

1. Make your own database and tables in MySQL.
2. Programatically open a file and parse each line to SQL.
3. Import the SQL into MySQL.
4. ???
5. Profit!

Yeah, I know I still haven't really told you anything, let's do one and you can hopefully do the others.

I'll do u.genre, because I'm lazy and it is easy.

Make a new table, I'll assume you know how to make tables and such.

u.genre has two things: a genre and an id.

```
 unknown|0
 Action|1
 ...etc...
```

So your table should have two fields.

You'll use two data types: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html

id - unsigned TINYINT

TINYINT unsigned is 0 to 255

genre - VARCHAR(20)

VARCHAR 20 is up to 20 characters, their longest is "Documentary" so that'll give you a bit of extra room if they add a new one.

Open the file get the contents: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents("u.genre");
```

Now let's split up the file by line: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$genres = explode("\n", $filecontents);
```

Now we'll loop through the $genres using foreach and explode again: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach ($genres as &$row) {
    list($genre,$id) = explode("|",$row);
    # more here later
}
```

Now let's just output SQL, skipping if either of the fields are empty.

```
if ($genre!="" && $id!=="") {
    print "INSERT INTO genre (genre,id) VALUES ($genre,$id);\n";
}
```

Put it all together...

```
<?php
$filecontents = file_get_contents("u.genre");
$genres = explode("\n", $filecontents);
foreach ($genres as &$row) {
    list($genre,$id) = explode("|",$row);
    if ($genre!="" && $id!=="") {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genre,id) VALUES ($genre,$id);\n";
        print $sql;
        # Insert each into your DB here.
    }
}
?>
```

Save it and run it from the commandline or put it in a browser for no good reason.

There are too many resources out there showing how to insert data into MySQL, so I'll leave it at this.  Everyone's database setup is a bit different, so writing it up for my particular setup won't help you.